# Deleted Neighborhood: $\sup(S)\not\in S\implies \sup(S)\in S'$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, elementary-set-theory

How is it that $\sup(S)\not\in S\implies \sup(S)\in S'$? Here, $S'$ is the set of limit points. I get that $N^*(x,\epsilon)\cap S\neq \varnothing$, but from here I don't know how to connect $\sup(S)\not\in S$.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to give a bit more context; I assume that $S\subseteq\Bbb R$. Suppose that $\sup S\notin S$, and for convenience let $s=\sup S$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary; then $s-\epsilon<s$, so by the definition of supremum there is some $x\in S$ such that $x>s-\epsilon$. Of course $x<s$, so $x\in N(x,\epsilon)$, and since $s\notin S$, we know that $x\ne s$. Thus, every open nbhd of $s$ contains a point of $S$ different from $s$, and therefore $s\in S'$: that’s exactly the definition of $s$ being a limit point of $S$.